# How can I place two nav elements left and center

Tags: html, css

I want to element 'a' to left of the page and element 'ul' to center of the page.

I don't want to use a library or a `float: left` option. Also `display: inline;` with `ul` element is not working, with other elements it works fine.

```
  <nav class="nav">
    <a href="">Brand</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a [routerLink]="['/hot']">Hot</a></li>
      <li><a [routerLink]="['/trend']">Trend</a></li>
      <li><a [routerLink]="['/new']">New</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Can you provide some CSS code, for example what you've tried so far. Also a bit better explanation would be nice, because this one is not very clear.

Comment: This is my best clear explanation. I can't speak English well, sorry.  And I want just 'a'  element left and 'ul' element center that's it.

Comment: @Somar: Don't add code snippets to code that isn't supposed to run.

Comment: @Cerbrus Why not? It will be useful to know how he is seeing his code to understand the way he wants it to be.

Comment: Can you update your question, so it is synced with accepted answer? Otherwise it can create confusion for people who later have the same question, but will find incorrect solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution (you wrote you want the `ul` centered): It makes the `ul`a centered `inline-block` and places the first `a` element left by making its `position` be `absolute` (and by default left-aligned).

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
}

nav>a {
  position: absolute;
}

nav ul {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <a href="">Brand</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/hot']">Hot</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/trend']">Trend</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/new']">New</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is also how I understood the question, and seems as nicer solution. Accepted solution seems to not even satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thank you. I accepted your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution below, using some display properties.

```css
ul,li{ margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style:none;}
.nav ul{display:inline}
.nav ul li{ display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <a href="">Brand</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a [routerLink]="['/hot']">Hot</a></li>
      <li><a [routerLink]="['/trend']">Trend</a></li>
      <li><a [routerLink]="['/new']">New</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```